# how to merge the two classes with two baseRepository<x> and baseRepository<y>

Tags: c#

I am trying to merge two classes with two BaseRepositorys

```
 1. public class xRepository : BaseRepository<x>, IxRepository{}
 2. public class yRepository : BaseRepository<y>, IyRepository{}
```

Can I write two BaseRepositorys together?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you're trying to do? I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "merge" the classes.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to provide more details about your classes but you can pass 2 types to an interface like this:

```
public class Repository : BaseRepository<x, y>, IxRepository, IyRepository
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you still want to keep both Repositories separate? Can you modify the BaseRepository class? There's a lot of info that you aren't providing.

One option though it to create a new Repository of the merged ones, and just inject via DI.

```
public class XRepository : BaseRepository<X>, IXRepository { }
public class YRepository : BaseRepository<Y>, IYRepository { }

public class ZRepository : BaseRepository<Z>, IZRepository
{
    private readonly IXRepository _xRepository;
    private readonly IYRepository _yRepository;

    public ZRepository(IXRepository xRepository, IYRepository yRepository)
    {
        _xRepository = xRepository;
        _yRepository = yRepository;
    }
}
```